# Filter object of objects and create new array with last 7 objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I filter/loop an object of objects in JavaScript to create a new array with only the last 7 objects? I know there are similar posts, but nothing that I can find that really clarifies my specific requirements.

I assume one might want to use .length and push items into the array, but I am not sure how.

**Also, sorting the array according to date would be essential in case the returned JSON is not already sorted.**

**This is an example of the object of objects in JSON:**

```
"uptime": {
    "2017-05-03": {
      "failures": 816, 
      "successes": 18378
    }, 
    "2017-05-04": {
      "failures": 1067, 
      "successes": 22302
    }, 
    "2017-05-05": {
      "failures": 1008, 
      "successes": 82599
    }, 
    "2017-05-07": {
      "failures": 2724, 
      "successes": 142854
    }, 
    "2017-05-08": {
      "failures": 1329, 
      "successes": 149028
    }, 
    "2017-05-09": {
      "failures": 3072, 
      "successes": 155432
    }, 
    "2017-05-10": {
      "failures": 22260, 
      "successes": 313944
    }, 
    "2017-05-11": {
      "failures": 8056, 
      "successes": 591864
    }, 
    "2017-05-15": {
      "failures": 1722, 
      "successes": 111285
    }, 
    "2017-05-16": {
      "failures": 8832, 
      "successes": 251142
    }, 
    "2017-05-17": {
      "failures": 2620, 
      "successes": 170140
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not an array. It's an object. Do you want to create an array of objects, or an object of objects?

Comment: Is it actually an array or is it an object, or is it in JSON format? Some current code example would help

Comment: Define "last 7". Is that based on the existing order of items in the object (which it doesn't have), or do you need to sort by something?

Comment: @LiamMacDonald it is as per the example. It is JSON and if I understand it correctly, it is an object of objects.

Comment: @deceze The last 7 only. No filtering apart from that. I.e., existing order.

Comment: Again, define what "last" means? That implies some sort of order. Define what that order is. (Again: objects are unordered.) Also define what the output is supposed to look like. Another "object of objects", or an array? What kind of array structure then?

Comment: @onmyway - What is being asked: Do you want the last 7 as you can see in your JSON? Or do you want it sorted by Date, and then the last 7?

Comment: @deceze the desired output would be an array of objects. In current order. the returned JSON orders it correctly, I simply want to create an array of the last 7 objects. Does this make sense?

Comment: What exactly would that resulting array look like? `[{ failures: ..., ...}, { failures: ..., ... }]`?

Comment: @shotor I suppose one could order it by date and select the last 7. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: I'll explicitly point out again that object properties have no guaranteed order. It may be ordered in your JSON, but as soon as you parse it into a Javascript object the order may or may not go out the window. If you want an ordered data structure, it needs to look somewhat different (use an array somewhere).

Comment: @onmyway, please update your question to reflect that and make 100% clear that you want to sort by date, then take the last (meaning latest) 7. Also change the text in `This is an example of the array`. - It's not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply take the values of your object ( the objects) and slice out the last seven from this:

```
var arr = Object.values( input.uptime ).slice(-7);
```

However, object key order is not defined in any way, so you might want to sort the array:

```
var arr=[];
for(key in input.uptime){
  input.uptime[key].time=key;
  arr.push(input.uptime[key]);
}
```

So now our array contains the objects with a time property, which can be sorted:

```
arr.sort((a,b)=>(new Date(a.time))-(new Date(b.time)));
```

And then sliced out:

```
arr=arr.slice(-7);
```

Comment: Whats with the downvotes? This is correct

Comment: @shotor It's only half the solution at best I would think.

Comment: @deceze well *how to create a new array with only the last 7 objects?* is answered here. What *last* means is impossible to tell based on the question...

Comment: @Jonas Exactly, so it's an unanswerable question at the moment.

Comment: @deceze thanks to the latest OP statement it is now an answer...

Comment: Since objects have no defined "current order"… hardly.

Comment: I think you were downvoted because your answer has a very low quality, describe the problem, provide a working code snippet, use ES6 `let/const` instead of `var` and use whitespaces.

Comment: @Jonasw thanks to the latest OP statement is it no longer an answer :) I'm sure you'll update it soon

Comment: @kind user yes i was missing a description, however posting a snippet is not possible as it isnt available on every device ( 66% of mys dont support them :/) , and we can discuss about let/const...